# Why flag[other processes] == true Petersen's Solution

Tags: operating-system, critical-section

I am recently studying Peterson's Solution to Critical Section problem.
Let i and j two processes entering critical section, 
I am not understanding why we set **flag[j] == true** in While loop when
its i's turn to enter critical section.

```
do
{
    flag[i] = true;
    turn = j;
    while(**flag[j] == true** && turn == j);
    Critical Section
    flag[i] = false;
} 
while(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> while(**flag[j] == true** && turn == j);

This line says that if the other process is executing its critical section, then the first process should keep on waiting till the second process sets its flag variable(shared variable) to false.

Only after the second process executes its critical section, and sets its flag variable(shared variable) to false, the first process would start executing its critical section.